# Drush command to switch to a multi-site child directory?

Tags: drush

Is there a Drush command that would `cd` into the directory of a particular multi-site instance, I mean to go to a directory like this one:

`/srv/www/drupal/sites/alpha`

where the parent Drupal resides in:

`/srv/www/drupal`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`drush status` produces a **Site Path** in its output which is what you're looking for. With some additional shell commands, you can parse this out.

```
MYPATH=/srv/www/drupal
MYDOMAIN=example.com

SITE_PATH=$(drush status --root=$MYPATH --uri=$MYDOMAIN | grep 'Site path' | cut -d':' -f2 | xargs)
cd "$MYPATH/$SITE_PATH"
```

Comment: Interesting.. But the same can be achieved using a bash alias e.g. `alias alpha = cd /srv/www/drupal/sites/alpha`, isn't it?

Comment: Sure. If you don't need to dynamically find the path.

Comment: Thank you for providing this valuable information.. I have learned new things from you code ..